# ADT Bundle unpacking

Tags: eclipse, passwords, adk

I downloaded the ADK eclipse bundle "adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/eclipse". When unpacking/extracting the files from zip, I was asked a password for several files. What is this password?

Answer (score 0):

Did you download this zip file from google developer site?
[This is the link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

then it shouldn't have any password protection.